# Check if username exist in database

Tags: django

Well i am creating a django based website and two user's can't have the same username. I want to check during registration if a username already exist then return a message in the register page to alert the person

views.py

```
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
```

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            emails = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list('email', flat=True)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            names = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list('username', flat=True)
           if username in names:
                messages.error(request, 'Sorry. This username is taken', extra_tags='name')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user.save()
                messages.success(request, "New account created")
                return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', {'form': form})
```

register.html

````
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
        {{message}}
    </div>
{% endfor %} ```


Some help would be nice
````

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the entered username exists in database. You can check that with [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#exists) method.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            emails = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list('email', flat=True)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'Sorry. This username is taken', extra_tags='name')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user.save()
                messages.success(request, "New account created")
                return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', {'form': form})
```

You don't need to check `is_active=True` with username check, because you have mentioned

> two user's can't have the same username

Answer (score 0):

Add your validation in the form using the clean method [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning).